# Calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I want to calculate the sum : $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1} $$
I differentiated it, so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{3n}$$
by putting $ x = \sqrt[3]{t}$ it becomes :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n$$
so $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$
by integrating it I should get the sum right ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that in your solution this only converges for $|t| < 1$.

Comment: yes i know but thank you, and for the rest ? does it give the sum im looking for ? if i integrate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^x x^{3n} dx = \int_{0}^x \frac{dx}{1-x^3}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now do partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1-x^3}= \frac{x+2}{3(1+x+x^2)}-\frac{1}{3(x-1)}
\end{eqnarray*}
Integrating this gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
S=\frac{1}{6} \ln(1+x+x^2)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)-\frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{3}} +\frac{1}{3} \ln(1-x)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I missed a $dx$ in the integral in the first line & ... @Winther points out the final answer needs $- \frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{3}}$ ... I will edit now.

Comment: $\int_0^x$ and $dx$?  :\

Answer (score 1):

This is false, the sum is a hypergeometric function:

$$
x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},1;\frac{4}{3};x^3\right).
$$

Comment: Note that there is no claim in the question (there was one in the title, but it was edited 3-4min before you answered).

Answer (score 0):

I just rechecked it, and i made a mistake, 
in the derivation, i shouldn't add and substract 1 because it'll start from 0 already, so  $F(x)$ should be  $$\int \frac{1}{1-x^3}dx$$.

Comment: If you find a mistake update the question, don't post an answer. You can answer your own question, but this is not a very useful answer for anybody else.

Comment: sorry, i'll update it now !